# sigsev error in containerized deeplearning4j app

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

Im running a deeplearning app in a docker container running openjdk alpine

```
    bash-4.4$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (Alpine 8.212.04-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Im running into SIGSEV errors as below

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000000021c6, pid=383, tid=0x00007f0f67879b10
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242-b08) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 3.15.0
# Distribution: Custom build (Wed Jan 29 10:53:09 UTC 2020)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000000021c6
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/xxx/xxxx/core or core.383
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:

#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

The libraries that are being imported are

```
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.exceptions.InvalidKerasConfigurationException;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.exceptions.UnsupportedKerasConfigurationException;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.IntBuffer;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.NDArray;
```

Looks like there is an existing issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213283
but wanted to know if there was any known work-around? 
I'm constrained to using open-jdk but can probably use a later version if that fixes this.

Comment: Assuming it's the same bug, yes. "Resolved: 2018-11-11 22:26" - go download a newer release from adoptopenjdk. Not sure why you needed to ask us.

Comment: Mind filing an issue? https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues